# CMD says NFS tools are missing, but Explorer says they're not

Tags: windows-8, command-line, mount, nfs, cmd.exe

I'm on Windows 8 x64 Enterprise Edition and I have the NFS Client/Server tools installed.
It was working perfectly fine for me a few months ago.

Today I wanted to mount some NFS shares, so I opened up a command prompt, typed "mount" and got an error: "'mount' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Surprised, I manually changed DIR to %windir%\system32 and ran a DIR, and ran "mount" but nothing came up.

But when I launched explorer and browsed to the folder, the files were present, and I was even able to launch them by double-clicking it.

[image]

If you check the above screenshot, you can see that both a normal and elevated cmd can't see the files, but explorer can.

File attribs are normal (only 'A'), and all users have read/execute permissions. I haven't touched UAC. I'm not running any special security software nor any antivirus. It doesn't seem to be affecting any other executables present in system32. My PATH variable looks fine as well.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the NFS tools, ran CHKDSK several times and rebooted, but nothing seems to have fixed it. Note that this is affecting *all* NFS tools - (nfsadmin, nsfshare, umount etc)

Is there any fix for this, short of a format+reinstall? More than the fix, I'm curious as to the actual reason this has occurred. In all my years of computing, I have never come across something like this. And no, cmd.exe isn't running in a sandbox or a virutal machine. The only thing close to a VM though is my C: is a VHDX and I'm booting off it, but that's never caused any issues before.

Would appreciate any thoughts on this issue.

Comment: Are you using the 32bit version of Xplorer Square? In that case 'C:\windows\system32' really shows the content of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64', use the 32bit version of cmd.exe

Comment: @PeterHahndorf : Good guess, but no, it's the 64bit version. Using the real explorer has the same result as well - it says the files are located in system32. Corollarily, cmd.exe also says mount.exe *isn't* present in SysWOW64.